# Why is $\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)} = \log_{x}(y)$?

Tags: logarithms

My question is in the title. Why is:

$$\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)} = \log_{x}(y)$$

I realize this was something I learned perhaps in middle school, but until my interest in more analytical math, I had never thought about the proof for it.

Comment: **HINT**: Start with $\log(x^a) = a\log x$.

Comment: Use exponential to prove.

Comment: How do you define $\log$ and $\log_x$? There are many ways to define these functions.

Comment: I like [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582575/intuition-behind-logarithm-change-of-base/2582599#2582599) to this previous question, but there are many others there for you to consult as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition behind logarithm change of base](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582575/intuition-behind-logarithm-change-of-base)

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question! I'll assume $\log$ is the natural logarithm (but any other base will work, of course).

We want to prove that $\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)} = \log_x(y)$.

$\log_x(y)$ **means** "the power to which $x$ must be raised to produce $y$", so in other words we need to prove that $$x^{\log(y)/\log(x)} = y.$$

Let's do it! We know that $x = e^{\log(x)}$, so we compute:

$$x^{\log(y)/\log(x)} = (e^{\log(x)})^{\log(y)/\log(x)} = e^{\log(y)} = y,$$

as desired. $\square$

---

For the pedants in the crowd: of course I did not start by giving a formal definition of $\log_x$, $e$, etc. However, this is clearly not the point of the question.

Comment: The definition of $\log$ is not pedantry: $\log_x(y)=\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)}$ could litterally be a definition. Actually, your answer defines $\log_x$! (As the inverse function of $t\mapsto x^t$)

Comment: @Taladris of course you're right! But I believe that OP is looking for *motivation* for this fact, not necessarily a proof. If this equality is definitional, then the correct proof is 1-line long, but the motivation behind the scenes is still something like what I wrote. My answer is phrased as a proof, but is really more a heuristic justification, saying "if you want arithmetic to have so-and-so usual properties, you need to also accept that $\log_x(y) = \log(x)/\log(y)$".

Comment: The point of my suggested approach was to avoid (the scarier) $x^b = e^{b\log x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another perspective on @diracdeltafunk's answer. By definition we have that $\log_x(y)$ is the solution (for $t$) of $x^t=y$. But we solve this exponential equation the way we solve any exponential equation; by taking logs (with respect to your favorite base):
\begin{align*}
    x^t &= y \\
    t \log(x) &= \log(y) \\
    t &= \log(y)/\log(x).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=\log_xy$. By the definition of logarithm, we can rewrite it as
$$x^z=y$$
Then taking logarithm on both sides yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \log \left(x^z\right)=\log y \\
\Leftrightarrow  \quad  &z \log x=\log y \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad  &z=\frac{\log y}{\log x} \\
\Leftrightarrow  \quad &\log _x y=\frac{\log y}{\log x}
\end{aligned}
$$